# MVC Identity Authorize attribute

Tags: asp.net-identity

I have 1 solution with 2 projects.
One of them is the MVC 5 Web Application with Authentication default structure.
The second one is an MVC 5 Empty application.

Can I use the [Authorize] from Identity in the Empty application?

The main pourpose is to centralize the authentication and authorization from the other web projects I have in the solution.